# how to get rid of spaces in excel when export through SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In case of tablix, suppose table has 5 column and we need to hide 3 column in this case if we set this property{=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", true, false)} on 3rd column then when we export to excel, we saw space in between 2nd and 4th row. How to get rid of spaces in excel?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you selected the cells in that column and the used the properties window ("F4") to set the `Hidden` property.

Instead, right click on the column header and set the *Column Visibility...*:

[image: Column Visibility]